# Using a variable in helm include (or template) for the name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I made a design for my helm chart which uses templates to set certain parts of my kubernetes deployment. The templates are per cloud provider:

A template for GCE, a template for AWS, etc.

The template is then included into the deployment part of the chart in Helm.

Now there is a pretty way of doing this which is:
Name every template according to the cloud provider it is intended for, and use a variable in the values.yaml to direct this.

And there is a less pretty way with a bunch of if statements.

I want to use the pretty way since it requires a lot less maintenance and code downstream, but can not get the following to work:

```
{{- include {{.Values.resources.cloudProvider}} .}}
```

In this statement the `{{.Values.resources.cloudProvider}}` contains my cloud provider name (aws, gce, etc)

The error I get is:

```
Error: parse error in "testModel/templates/deployment.yaml": 
template: testModel/templates/deployment.yaml:28: 
unexpected "{" in operand
```

The other method I tested is:

```
{{- include (.Values.resources.cloudProvider) .}}
```

Which gives:

```
Error: render error in "testModel/templates/deployment.yaml": template:
testModel/templates/deployment.yaml:29:23: 
executing "testModel/templates/deployment.yaml" 
at <.Values.resources.c...>: invalid value; expected string
```

Is there a way to use a variable for a template name when including the template?

Comment: `{{` never goes directly within itself.  This is true of any analogous escape sequence, such as jinja `{%`, even php.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using helm 2.4.2.  This work by changing the line

> {{- include {{.Values.resources.cloudProvider}} .}}

to:

> {{- include .Values.resources.cloudProvider .}}

You can also use a variable:

> {{- $provider := .Values.resources.cloudProvider -}}
>   {{ - include $provider . }}